# In R can you create an in-memory Teradata database?

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, teradata, dbplyr

[dbplyr's reference page](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/index.html) begins showing how to create an in-memory SQLite database and copy over a dataset:

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
con1 <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
copy_to(con1, mtcars)
```

It does this utizing `RSQLite::SQLite()`. Is there a similar way to create an in-memory **Teradata** database and copy over a dataset. I'd imagine it could look something like:

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
con2 <- DBI::dbConnect(RTeradata::Teradata(), ":memory:")
copy_to(con2, iris)
```

Looking around it seems there's no such thing as `RTeradata::Teradata()` so I'm not sure what to do.

If you're curious about my motivations I want to be able to create reproducible examples of errors I get while using dbplyr with Teradata SQL databases. I don't know of a way to do this at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the  `DBI` package after installing the [teradara drivers](https://github.com/Teradata/r-driver). If you want something specifically for `dplyr`, have a look at [tdplyr](https://github.com/Teradata/tdplyr).